# Accessing Advanced Custom Fields Data in Zapier

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, zapier

I am using zapier to connect to my Wordpress site.  That is to say, I want to use zapier to create a new post from a [Feedly feed](https://feedly.com/) and have certain custom fields populated from data from that feed.  Now, part of this works.  I can create a new post in my custom post type.  But, zapier does not show any of the custom fields that I have created for that post type.

I am wondering, does anyone know how to get zapier to display that custom fields (or some other way to populate those custom fields?

NOTE:  I created the custom post type using the [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) plugin.  I created the custom fields using [Advanced Custom Fields Pro](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).